# Windows wont recognize my Boot SD card

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

I have a `aarch64` architecture SD card with Ubuntu inside. I would like to make a copy of data inside, but my Windows 10 wont recognize the SD card. (not in `PC` folder) so I cant select it with `Win32 Disk Imager`, But it makes a connection sound when I connect the card and the card is recognized by `Mini Tool partition Wizard` and `Windows Partition Tool` as well. Also I have no problems with normally formatted cards or usbs. Is it some new silly `Windows feature` or what? Btw. No, the card is not corrupted or broken, just `ext4` format with OS inside

Answer (score 0):

Windows are not able to use ext4 without the use of an external application. If your sd is not assigned a drive letter you can open disk management and assign one. I [link](https://domoticproject.com/doing-raspberry-pi-backup/) a guide for a pi backup that should be similar to what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not able to assign a letter. It say that `the information are not updated` and when I update it, just say the same stuff... probably not possible? But I remember I was able to backup it about 6 months ago...